# Proving that $ X$ is homeomorphic to $ Y / A $

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I want to solve the following exercise:

###### Exercise

Suppose that $ X $ and $ Y $ are compact Hausdorff topological spaces and $ A \subset Y $ is non-empty and closed.
Let $ x_0 \in X $ be a point.
Prove that if $ \varphi \colon X \setminus \{ x_0 \} \to Y \setminus A $ is a homeomorphism, then there exists a homeomorphism $ f \colon X \to Y / A $.

I think that I can intuitively see why this is true, but I cannot formally prove this statement.

###### My attempt

Let $ f $ be given by
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    (q \circ \varphi)(x) &\text{ if } x \neq x_0 \, , \\
    a &\text{ otherwise} \, ,
\end{cases}
$$
where $ q \colon Y \to Y / A $ is the quotient map and $ a \in q(A) \subset Y / A $ is a fixed point.
Since $ \varphi $ and $ q \colon Y \setminus A \to Y / A $ are homeomorphisms (we restricted $ q $ to $ Y \setminus A $ - this is a homeomorphism onto its image), we know that $ f $ is a bijection.
We need to prove that $ f(U) $ is open for any open $ U \subset X $ and $ f^{-1}(O) $ is open for any open $ O \subset Y / A $.
Let $ U \subset X $.
If $ x_0 \not \in U $, then $ f(U) $ is clearly open in $ Y / A $, because $ f(U) = (q \circ \varphi)(U) $.
If $ x_0 \in U $, then
$$
f(U) 
            = f(U \setminus \{ x_0 \}) \cup f(\{ x_0 \}) 
            = (q \circ \varphi)(U \setminus \{ x_0 \}) \cup \{ a \} \, .
$$
Let $ f(U) = W $.
We know that $ W $ is open if and only if $ q^{-1}(W) = \varphi(U \setminus \{ x_0 \}) \cup A $ is open.

I don't know how to proceed from here. Similarly, I do not know how to prove $ f^{-1}(O) $ is open given an open $ O \subset Y / A $ such that $ a \in O $, but it seems to me that the proof must use a very similar argument.
I imagine we now need to use the compactness of $ X $, $ Y $, and $ A $ somehow, but I've no idea how.

Comment: I don't think that "$ q \colon Y \setminus A \to Y / A $ [is a] homeomorphism".

Comment: @AnneBauval How come? Also, I didn't really try to use the fact that it is a homeomorphism (even though I said so) - for what I tried to achieve it's enough that it is an open map and a bijection (between $ Y \setminus A $ and $ Y / A \setminus \{ a \} $.

Comment: $q \colon Y \setminus A \to Y / A$ is not onto.

Comment: I meant $ q \colon Y \setminus A \to Y / A $ is a homeomorphism onto its image $ q(Y \setminus A) = Y / A \setminus \{ a \} $.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove $f$ is closed. Suppose $Z \subset X$ is closed, so compact.

If $x_0 \notin Z$ then $f(Z) = \varphi(Z)$ is compact. Since $A$ is closed, $Z/A$ is Hausdorff, so $f(Z)$ is closed.

If $x_0 \in Z$ then $Z \setminus x_0$ is closed in $X \setminus x_0$, so $\varphi(Z \setminus x_0)$ is closed in $Y \setminus A$, which is to say that $\overline{\varphi(Z \setminus x_0)} \subset \varphi(Z \setminus x_0) \cup A$, where the closure is taken in $Y$. Since $A$ is closed, $q^{-1}(f(Z)) = \varphi(Z \setminus x_0) \cup A = \overline{\varphi(Z \setminus x_0)} \cup A$ is closed. By the definition of quotient topology, this means that $f(Z)$ is closed.

The proof that $f$ is continuous by showing that $f^{-1}(Z)$ is closed for $Z \subset Y/A$ is closed is very similar: either $Z \subset (Y/A) \setminus a$ and therefore $f^{-1}(Z) = \varphi^{-1}(Z)$ is compact, or $f^{-1}(Z) = \overline{\varphi^{-1}(Z)} \cup \{x_0\}$.

Once you have one of the directions you could also use the general fact that a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed, so such a bijection is automatically a homeomorphism.